# GCP: Stack driver Global error logs not going to error reporting

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I have errors correctly appearing in [stack driver log viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZPzq.png) but not in [error reporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOR70.png).

Its a python application that uses `google-cloud-logging` to set up the stack driver logger. I'd think that would do the job but apparently not. Here is how I set it up

```py
import logging
import google.cloud.logging # Don't conflict with standard logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler, setup_logging
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO) # defaults to WARN
setup_logging(handler)
```

Any clues why it doesn't appear in error reporting? The service account have the following roles

- Error Reporting Admin
- Errors Writer
- Logging Admin

Comment: I created a bug here https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/4253 you can get more info

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps double check the [formatting requirements](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages#formatting_requirements), if the format is not quite correct it will not be ingested into error reporting. The screenshot of the message looks ok but you can double check with the API for ReportedErrorEvent from that link. Also which platform is being used? The setup can vary slightly depending on the platform, see the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup) here.  I don't think the roles would be an issue for the ingestion.

Comment: I have one running on App Engine where it works just fine but the one running on a compute instance does not work. Looking at the logs they differ on `ressource`. One being `gae_app` the other being `global`. I can't figure out how to make it work on a vm instance